# How Do I perform an outer Join in C# using three tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to get the list of roles and the total number of users in each of the roles. So far, this works:

```
var result = (from r in _context.UserRoles
                          join u in _context.Users on r.UserId equals u.Id
                          group new { r, u } by new { r.RoleId } into grp
                          select new UserRoleModel { RoleId = (int)grp.FirstOrDefault().r.RoleId, NoOfUsers = grp.Count() }).ToList();
```

But it does not display roles that don't have any users in it. I have 12 roles, 7 of them have been assigned to at least one user, while the remaining 5 have not. I want to display all the roles with the number of users assigned to them, but if the roles have no users assigned to them (like those 5) I want it to return 0 as the number of users. Thanks

Comment: I think you need a `DefaultIfEmpty` for an outer join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq, where is the third table in your example?

Comment: When I see questions like this, where you need to go to great lengths to write linq which is almost like SQL, I wonder, why  not just write the SQL, it will run faster and be more predictable.

Comment: Three tables? I only see two. Doesn't `UserRole` have a property `User`? You shouldn't have to code joins explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply `left join` and you should join them using `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Also, the entities which is joined in the query is wrong. Because, you should join junction entity (`UserRole`) with `Role` entity instead of `User` if you want to retrieve the grouped roles and count of opposite users. Otherwise, you never know which role doesn't have user.

```
var result = (from r in _context.Roles
    join ur in _context.UserRoles on r.Id equals ur.RoleId into ps
    from ur in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { r,ur } by new { r.Id } into grp
    select new UserRoleModel { RoleId = (int)grp.Key.Id, 
    NoOfUsers = grp.Count(t => t.ur != null) }).ToList();
```

Also, I suggest you to change

`(int)grp.FirstOrDefault().r.RoleId`

to

```
(int)grp.Key.RoleId
```

The query is grouped by `RoleId` already.

Also, I have additional note. I strongly suggest you to define navigation properties and use them. If you would have them in the entities, the query would be simplier;

```
var result = _context.Roles.Select(x => new UserRoleModel
{
    RoleId = x.Id,
    NoOfUsers = x.UserRoles?.Count() ?? 0
});
```

Comment: I Tried this, it still generates only roles with with users assigned to them. I have 12 roles, 7 of them have been assigned to at least one user, while the remaining 5 have not. I want to display all the roles with the number of users assigned to them, but if the roles have no users assigned to them (like those 5) I want it to return 0 as the number of users. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!...Works like a charm!.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var result = (from r in _context.UserRoles
         join u in _context.Users on r.UserId equals u.Id into temp
         from uu in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
         group new { r, u } by new { r.RoleId } into grp
         select new UserRoleModel { RoleId = (int)grp.FirstOrDefault().r.RoleId, NoOfUsers = grp.Count() }).ToList();
```